# How to set Principal to RestAssuredMockMvc or MockMvc in @Before method?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using RestAssuredMockMvc and MockMvc in my tests. 
I've created Principal Bean.
And now I need to inject this bean in many tests.

This test works fine:

```
@Test
    public void principalTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/current")
                .principal(myPrincipalBean))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

But I need to set `.(myPrincipalBean))` not for every test manually, I need to set myPrincipalBean as part of RestAssuredMockMvc or MockMvc in @Before method method here:

```
@Before
    public void settingUpTests() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(
                new Controller(Service));
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .build();
        RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
    }
```

I tried to use `RestAssuredMockMvc.principal(myPrincipalBean);` but IDE marked this method as ignored.

So how can I set my created Principal Bean into the RestAssuredMockMvc or MockMvc? 
Or how can I use `RestAssuredMockMvc.principal(myPrincipalBean)` method without ignoring?

Answer (score 0):

I found location.

```
RestAssuredMockMvc.authentication = RestAssuredMockMvc.principal(oAuth2Authentication);
```

If somebody will need this answer.